# Keyboard hides automatically on key press in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I'm creating a form, where I need to input the data in the field. But as soon as I press the key, the keyboard is hiding automatically and I'm unable to do persistent typing.

Suppose, I'm typing a Product name or stock anything the typing is persistent but when I type in variants section on every keypress keyboards hides automatically.

Here is the codebase-

**AddNewProductScreen.js**

```
....

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  product: {
    name: '',
    category: '',
    type: 'packet',
    brand: '',
    variants: [
      {
        value: '',
        price: '',
      },
    ],
    stock: '',
  },
};

....

<Input
  inputContainerStyle={{borderBottomColor: 'transparent'}}
  inputComponent={() => (
    <View>
      {this.state.product.variants.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={[mainStyles.row, {marginTop: 10}]}>
          <View style={mainStyles.col6}>
            <Input
              label="Value"
              placeholder="500 gm or 1 pc"
              value={this.state.product.variants[index].value}
              onChangeText={value => {
                let variants = this.state.product.variants;
                variants[index].value = value;
                this.setState({
                  product: {
                    ...this.state.product,
                    variants,
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={mainStyles.col5}>
            <Input
              label="Price"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              placeholder="50"
              value={this.state.product.variants[index].price}
              onChangeText={price => {
                let variants = this.state.product.variants;
                variants[index].price = price;
                this.setState({
                  product: {
                    ...this.state.product,
                    variants,
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={[mainStyles.col1, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
            <Icon
              name="times"
              size={25}
              color="red"
              type="font-awesome"
              containerStyle={{
                display: `${
                  this.state.product.variants.length > 1 ? 'flex' : 'none'
                }`,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                let variants = this.state.product.variants;
                variants.splice(index, 1);
                this.setState({
                  product: {
                    ...this.state.product,
                    variants,
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  )}
/>
....
```

**Expectation:** Inside the variants input(Value & Price), I need persistent typing as of other input fields.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Applicatio screen shot]

**P.S-** adding the screenshot for reference

Comment: I think It happens due to setState() in onChange.

Answer (score 0):

```
      {this.state.product.variants.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={[mainStyles.row, {marginTop: 10}]}>
          <View style={mainStyles.col6}>
            <Input
              label="Value"
              placeholder="500 gm or 1 pc"
              value={this.state.product.variants[index].value}
              onChangeText={value => {
                let variants = this.state.product.variants;
                variants[index].value = value;
                this.setState({
                  product: {
                    ...this.state.product,
                    variants,
                  },
                });
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

Problem here is that `this.state.product.variants` is changing based on values in the input fields, and thus the contents in this list is mounted again on each keypress. I suggest you try an approach that does not map the input fields and they will remain in the component tree throughout the lifecycle of the parent.